# Pandas: Sorting rows based on a value of a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` like this :

```
ID    NAME    AGE
-----------------
M43   ab      32
M32   df      12
M54   gh      34
M43   ab      98
M43   ab      36
M43   cd      32
M32   cd      39
M43   ab      67
```

I need to sort the rows based on the `ID` column.
The output `df_grouped` should look like :

```
ID    NAME    AGE
-----------------
M43   ab      32
M43   ab      98
M43   ab      36
M43   cd      32
M43   ab      67
M32   df      12
M32   cd      39
M54   gh      34
```

I tried something like :

```
df_grouped = df.group_by(df.ID)

for id in list(df.ID.unique()):
   grouped_df_list.append(df_grouped.get_group(id))
```

Is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: That doesn't look like grouping - more like sorting... isn't `df.sort_values('ID')` what you're after?

Comment: Unfortunately my example looks like that, the `ID` column has - say 6 unique entries, I need to group rows in these six chunks.

Comment: Add more data and show an sample output with grouping of six, please.

Comment: @deadbug what's the difference between grouping the 6 and appending them to a new frame, than just sorting them so the keys are together then - I'm not following...

Comment: okay, let me update the question little bit. Hold on please

Comment: @JonClements is it now makes sense ?

Comment: You want to have rows with identical IDs adjacent to each other but retain the order they originally appeared in the frame right? If so - your code example makes more sense - just a fairly poor choice of sample data and lack of explanation :)

Comment: I want to have rows with identical IDs adjacent to each other. That's it ! If it retains order of appearance that's fine, but not mandatory.

Comment: @deadbug you can just use `sort_values` on `ID`. Try it.

Comment: @deadbug note that unless you pass `sort=False` your code might not even end up working quite how you think anyway.... I've provided an example using `pd.factorize` which I think is what you're after... Might be worth reading up on that and `.argsort()` if you're not already familiar with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort by multiple columns using [`pd.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'NAME'])
```

By default, the argument `ascending` is set to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.factorize` to turn the key into a unique number which represents the order it appeared, then argsort that to get the positions to index into your frame, eg:

Given:

```
     0   1   2
0  M43  ab  32
1  M32  df  12
2  M54  gh  34
3  M43  ab  98
4  M43  ab  36
5  M43  cd  32
6  M32  cd  39
7  M43  ab  67
```

Then:

```
new_df = df.loc[pd.factorize(df[0])[0].argsort()]
# might want to consider df.reindex() instead depending...
```

You get:

```
     0   1   2
0  M43  ab  32
3  M43  ab  98
4  M43  ab  36
5  M43  cd  32
7  M43  ab  67
1  M32  df  12
6  M32  cd  39
2  M54  gh  34
```